# Spark RDDs: How to join value in a Map to a row in an RDD

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, mapping, hdfs

I have a csv file that I am loading into Spark as an RDD with:

```
val home_rdd = sc.textFile("hdfs://path/to/home_data.csv")
val home_parsed = home_rdd.map(row => row.split(",").map(_.trim))
val home_header = home_parsed.first
val home_data = home_parsed.filter(_(0) != home_header(0))
```

`home_data` then is:

```
scala> home_data
res17: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[String]] = MapPartitionsRDD[3] at filter at <console>:30

scala> home_data.take(3)
res20: Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array("7129300520", "20141013T000000", 221900, "3", "1", 1180, 5650, "1", 0, 0, 3, 7, 1180, 0, 1955, 0, "98178", 47.5112, -122.257, 1340, 5650), Array("6414100192", "20141209T000000", 538000, "3", "2.25", 2570, 7242, "2", 0, 0, 3, 7, 2170, 400, 1951, 1991, "98125", 47.721, -122.319, 1690, 7639), Array("5631500400", "20150225T000000", 180000, "2", "1", 770, 10000, "1", 0, 0, 3, 6, 770, 0, 1933, 0, "98028", 47.7379, -122.233, 2720, 8062))
```

I also have a csv of zipcodes to neighborhoods loaded as RDD then used to create a map that is a `Map[String,String]` with:

```
val zip_rdd = sc.textFile("hdfs://path/to/zipcodes.csv")
val zip_parsed = zip_rdd.map(row => row.split(",").map(_.trim))
val zip_header = zip_parsed.first
val zip_data = zip_parsed.filter(_(0) != zip_header(0))
val zip_map = zip_data.map(row => (row(0), row(1))).collectAsMap
val zip_ind = home_header.indexOf("zipcode") //to get the zipcode column in home_data
```

Where:

```
scala> zip_map.take(3)
res21: scala.collection.Map[String,String] = Map(98151 -> Seattle, 98052 -> Redmond, 98104 -> Seattle)
```

What I am trying to do next is iterate through `home_data` and use the zipcode value in each row (at `zip_ind` = 16) to fetch the neighborhood value from `zip_map` and append that value to the end of the row.

```
val zip_processed = home_data.map(row => row :+ zip_map.get(row(zip_ind)))
```

But each time it fetches from zip_map, something is failing and so it only appends `None` to the end of each row in home_data

```
scala> zip_processed.take(3)
res19: Array[Array[java.io.Serializable]] = Array(Array("7129300520", "20141013T000000", 221900, "3", "1", 1180, 5650, "1", 0, 0, 3, 7, 1180, 0, 1955, 0, "98178", 47.5112, -122.257, 1340, 5650, None), Array("6414100192", "20141209T000000", 538000, "3", "2.25", 2570, 7242, "2", 0, 0, 3, 7, 2170, 400, 1951, 1991, "98125", 47.721, -122.319, 1690, 7639, None), Array("5631500400", "20150225T000000", 180000, "2", "1", 770, 10000, "1", 0, 0, 3, 6, 770, 0, 1933, 0, "98028", 47.7379, -122.233, 2720, 8062, None))
```

I am trying to debug this, but am not sure why it's failing at `zip_map.get(row(zip_ind))`.

I am fairly green with Scala so maybe I am making some bad assumptions, but trying to figure out how to better understand what is happening in the map function.

Answer (score 1):

Map.get() returns `None` when there is no match.  You can use `getOrElse` to append the Map value with a fall-back:

```
val home_data = sc.parallelize(Array(
  Array("7129300520", "20141013T000000", 221900, "3", "1", 1180, 5650, "1", 0, 0, 3, 7, 1180, 0, 1955, 0, "98178", 47.5112, -122.257, 1340, 5650),
  Array("6414100192", "20141209T000000", 538000, "3", "2.25", 2570, 7242, "2", 0, 0, 3, 7, 2170, 400, 1951, 1991, "98125", 47.721, -122.319, 1690, 7639),
  Array("5631500400", "20150225T000000", 180000, "2", "1", 770, 10000, "1", 0, 0, 3, 6, 770, 0, 1933, 0, "98028", 47.7379, -122.233, 2720, 8062)
))

val zip_ind = 16
val zip_map: Map[String, String] = Map("98178" -> "A", "98028" -> "B")

val zip_processed = home_data.map(row => row :+ zip_map.getOrElse(row(zip_ind).toString, "N/A"))

zip_processed.collect
// res1: Array[Array[Any]] = Array(
//   Array(7129300520, 20141013T000000, 221900, 3, 1, 1180, 5650, 1, 0, 0, 3, 7, 1180, 0, 1955, 0, 98178, 47.5112, -122.257, 1340, 5650, A),
//   Array(6414100192, 20141209T000000, 538000, 3, 2.25, 2570, 7242, 2, 0, 0, 3, 7, 2170, 400, 1951, 1991, 98125, 47.721, -122.319, 1690, 7639, N/A),
//   Array(5631500400, 20150225T000000, 180000, 2, 1, 770, 10000, 1, 0, 0, 3, 6, 770, 0, 1933, 0, 98028, 47.7379, -122.233, 2720, 8062, B)
// )
```

Comment: Thanks, but I believe I tried that and I believe the problem is more that in either approach, all output is either `None` or `N/A` if I use `getOrElse` so the issue is that nothing is matching even though I know that there are values at index 16 in each row that map to something in `zip_map`

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not able to replicate the described problem.